# How to share location of one user app with other app in flutter using firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-maps, geolocation, location

i am making a flutter app just like careem/uber in which when a provider goes online, it's location marker becomes visible on map to the user(on another user app) then user selects that provider and sends him request. On accepting request live location of provider is shared with user on map. How to achieve this kindly help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Firebase Realtime Database to do that. The provider will send the coordinates to the database and the connected user will get the location in real-time.

If you are capable of managing the server then WebSocket would be great!.

Comment: Thankyou, i'll try to  use streams to store  updated live location coordinates of Provider  in firebase and then User app will fetch that coordinates for tracking.